# Search keywords and retrieve whole sentence

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I use `SELECT id FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%{$keyword}%';` which simply works but I wonder how it is possible to show few surrounding words before and after the keyword. See the example for better understanding:

keyword:

**music**

Text (a text field in MySQL):

> Tender Mercies is a 1983 American drama film. Robert Duvall (pictured) plays Mac Sledge, a recovering alcoholic country **music** singer who seeks to turn his life around through his relationship with a young widow and her son in rural Texas. Duvall, who sang his own songs in the film, drove more than 600 miles (966 km) throughout the state, tape recording local accents and playing in country **music** bands to prepare for the role. He and director Bruce Beresford repeatedly clashed during production, at one point prompting Beresford to walk off the set and reportedly consider quitting.

And retrieve this:

- ... plays Mac Sledge, a recovering alcoholic country **music** singer who seeks to turn his life ...
- ... tape recording local accents and playing in country **music** bands to prepare for the role. ...

Finally, I am using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1st. Create mysql function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) which will process full text and generating cutted sentences.

2nd. Fetch full text in php and process text to generate cutted sentences.

In both ways you have to do this by custom functions.

I prefer second way, because code in php file is easy to support in future.